# Adding dynamic url in a reverse function in django

Tags: django

I'm building a blog app, and when posting a comment, and a reply to a comment, the page redirects to the top of the post page, I want it to redirect into the comment\reply that was posted, or scroll into it if you will.

for example, when posting, I want it to go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/first#comment-12
to implement something like this:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(f'post_page#comment-{str(comment.id)}', kwargs={ 'slug': slug }))
```

views.py

```
if request.POST:
    comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    if comment_form.is_valid:
        if request.POST.get('parent'):
            parent_id = request.POST.get('parent')
            parent = Comments.objects.get(id=parent_id)
            if parent:
                comment_reply = comment_form.save(commit=False)
                comment_reply.parent = parent
                comment_reply.post = post
                comment_reply.save()
        else:
            comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            post_id = request.POST.get('post_id')
            post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post_page', kwargs={ 'slug': slug }))
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('post/<slug:slug>', views.post_page, name='post_page')
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add the fragment manually at the end of the path, like:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(f"{reverse('post_page', kwargs={ 'slug': slug })}#comment-{comment.id}")
```

I think the [**`redirect(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) and [**`reverse(…)`** functions <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) could have benefited from an optional `_anchor` parameter that would append the anchor (and also URL encode it).

Comment: Wow awesome thanks! is there a way to add a smooth animation?

Comment: Agree, but it id="comment-{{comment.id}}"  also shoild be added in html template

Comment: @A-Makeyev: that will be more JavaScript/css I guess. But since it makes a redirect, so to a different page, likely it will at least have to reload the page.

Comment: in css of page you can use html {scroll-behavior: smooth;}